# Delete lines that contain the same letter more than 3 times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code which deletes lines if they contain the same letter 3 times. I need it to delete the line if the letter is repeated more than 3 times (separated).

3 times (separated) I mean for example this line `BAABAAG`. Notice this line contains the letter `A` four times but my code did not delete it because the four letters `A` are not beside each other.

```
bad_words = ['AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','EEE','FFF','GGG','HHH','III','JJJ','KKK','LLL','MMM','NNN','OOO','PPP','QQQ','RRR','SSS','TTT','UUU','VVV','WWW','XXX','YYY','ZZZ','111','222','333','444','555','666','777','888','999','000']

with open('7.csv') as oldfile, open('new7.csv', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
            newfile.write(line)
```

**Sample of the file:**

```
BAABAAB
BAABAAC
BAABAAD
BAABAAE
BAABAAF
BAABAAG
BAABAAH
BAABAAI
BAABAAJ
BAABAAK
BAABAAL
BAABAAM
BAABAAN
BAABAAO
BAABAAP
BAABAAQ
```

Comment: What does it mean  `more than 3 times (separated)`? Can you post some example input with the desired output?

Comment: @alec_djinn  3 times (separated) I means for example this line (BAABAAG) notice this line contains chart (A) four times but my code did not delete it because the four chart (A) not (beside each others)

Comment: @aaddkah So looking at your sample file - nothing will be deleted?

Comment: Simply use `line.count('A')` then...

Comment: @Andrej Kesely actually in my sample file , ALL lines should be deleted because chart (A) is repeated 4 times

Comment: What's chart (A)? I'm confused about what should and shouldn't be deleted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to explicitly create a `bad_words` list, you can set it as `repeater` variable as well

```
repeater = 3
newlist = []

with open('input.txt') as f:    
    x = f.readlines()
    for val in x:
        word = val.split('\n')[0]
        flag = True
        for letter in word:
            if letter.upper() * repeater in word:
                flag = False
                break
        if flag:
            newlist.append(word)
    newlist = list(set(newlist))


with open('output.txt', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as newfile:
    for value in newlist:
        newfile.writelines(value+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single characters instead of a list of triplets and `string.count()`. Making a little function to encapsulate the filtering logic is probably a good option as well.

```
def f(line, chars, limit):
    for char in chars:
        if line.count(char) > limit:
            return False
    return True

bad_chars = ['A','B', ...]

with open('7.csv', 'r') as oldfile, open('new7.csv', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if f(line, bad_chars, 3):
            newfile.write(line)
```

Comment: your `f` function is equivalent to `all(line.count(char) <= limit for char in chars)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Indeed. I never use ‘all()’, in this case really makes sense. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that will check if a character appears more than 3 times and just call it in your code:

```
def letter_count(str):
    counts = dict()

    for l in str:
        if l in counts:
            counts[l] += 1
        else:
            counts[l] = 1
    counts[max(counts, key=lambda x : counts[x])]

    return counts[max(counts, key=lambda x : counts[x])] > 3
```

and call it in your code like this:

```
with open('7.csv') as oldfile, open('new7.csv', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if if(letter_count(line)):
            newfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to check the frequencies of the different letters in each line and then write this line only if they didn't pass your threshold:

```py
from collections import Counter

threshold = 3
with open('7.csv') as oldfile, open('new7.csv', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        counts = Counter(line)
        if all(count < threshold for count in counts.values()):
            newfile.write(line)
```

This uses the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function to make sure there is no letter passing the threshold.